# CSS position fixed not working despite me not having filter/transform/will-change/etc

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I stumbled on some draggable div code on w3schools, which I thought would make a cheap vanilla lightweight windowing interface.  I tweaked it a little to see how it would behave with a pseudo-toolbar and main area, and I ran into the infamous "position:fixed not working" bug/feature.

The popup panes are styled with position:fixed, so should be generating at the top-left of the viewport, but instead are appearing below the main area.  If the main area were to take up the entire height (after the toolbar), the popups would generate offscreen and be inaccessible.

What I don't get is, I'm not using any of the so-called properties that trigger the position-fixed-not-working-thing.

Here's my code that does what I just described:

`

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><style>

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#toolbar {
  background-color: lightgray;
}

button {
  height: 40px;
  width: 50px;
}

#mainArea {
  height: 500px;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
}

.mydiv {
  position: fixed;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
}

</style><body>

<div id="toolbar">
   <button onclick="cbPopup()">Popup</button>
</div>

<div id="mainArea">
   <p>Main Area</p>
</div>

<script>

function cbPopup()
{
  var aDiv  = document.createElement("div");
  aDiv.className = "mydiv";
  aDiv.innerHTML = "<p>What a pane</p><p>What a pane</p><p>What a pane</p>";
  dragElement(aDiv);
  document.body.appendChild(aDiv);
}

function dragElement(elmnt) {
  var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;
  if (document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header")) {
    /* if present, the header is where you move the DIV from:*/
    document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header").onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  } else {
    /* otherwise, move the DIV from anywhere inside the DIV:*/
    elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  }

  function dragMouseDown(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
  }

  function elementDrag(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // calculate the new cursor position:
    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    // set the element's new position:
    elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
    elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
  }

  function closeDragElement() {
    /* stop moving when mouse button is released:*/
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }
}
</script></body></html>
```

`

Answer (score 1):

**Why it happened**

This behavior of `position: fixed` is normal.

It positions the pop-up relative to its initial container `body`. When the pop-up is created with `append`, `body` lists it after the other elements, naturally. That spot get fixed as its initial position, causing it to appear after `mainArea`.

[More about `position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

**Solution**

To make the pop-up appear at the top (or other desired locations), you can make a container for it at the desired spot, and `append` it in the container.

Example:

```
<!-- Place this at desired location for pop-up in HTML -->
<div id="container"></div>
```

```
var aContainer = document.querySelector("#container");
aContainer.appendChild(aDiv);
```

Hope this will help!

Full example: **(run it live with the button below)**

```js
function cbPopup() {
  var aDiv = document.createElement("div");
  aDiv.className = "mydiv";
  aDiv.innerHTML = "<p>What a pane</p><p>What a pane</p><p>What a pane</p>";
  dragElement(aDiv);

  var aContainer = document.querySelector("#container");
  aContainer.appendChild(aDiv);
}

function dragElement(elmnt) {
  var pos1 = 0,
    pos2 = 0,
    pos3 = 0,
    pos4 = 0;
  if (document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header")) {
    /* if present, the header is where you move the DIV from:*/
    document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header").onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  } else {
    /* otherwise, move the DIV from anywhere inside the DIV:*/
    elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  }

  function dragMouseDown(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
  }

  function elementDrag(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // calculate the new cursor position:
    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    // set the element's new position:
    elmnt.style.top = elmnt.offsetTop - pos2 + "px";
    elmnt.style.left = elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1 + "px";
  }

  function closeDragElement() {
    /* stop moving when mouse button is released:*/
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#toolbar {
  background-color: lightgray;
}

button {
  height: 40px;
  width: 50px;
}

#mainArea {
  height: 500px;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
}

.mydiv {
  position: fixed;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
}
```

```html
<!-- Place this at desired location for pop-up in HTML -->
<div id="container"></div>

<div id="toolbar">
   <button onclick="cbPopup()">Popup</button>
</div>

<div id="mainArea">
   <p>Main Area</p>
</div>
```

Comment: @ReeAzz Glad that it helps! Please accept this answer so the post is complete. Thanks.